# High level @Html.DropDownListFor() parameter explaination

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-select

I have a question opened on S.O. dealing with an implementation of this drop down but i'm getting hung up on using a model with it.

So two questions:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Id, new SelectList(ViewBag.CompanyList as System.Collections.IEnumerable,"CoId","CompanyName"))
```

What is m=>m.Id actually doing here?

Is "CoId" being set to value and "CompanyName" set to text?

Here is my model:

```
public class CompanyViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    }
    public class CompanyViewModelDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<CompanyViewModel> Contacts { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`m => m.Id` is setting the `Id` property of the `Model` as the value being governed by the drop down (which will also set the selected value on load).

`,"CoId","CompanyName"` is defining which properties of your `IEnumerable` items are being used as the *value* and the *text*.  It's saying, "Use `CoId` as the value and display `CompanyName` in the dropdown for each item in `ViewBag.CompanyList`."

As **BetaSystems - Rodrigo D** says, since you don't have a `CoId` property, you should change it to `Id`.

Comment: Ah alright, not sure why I got a down vote for the question but ok. Thanks for the responses. I'll take a look at this tomorrow.  The reason I have coid is because that's what is stored in the view bag.

Comment: What you're looking for is the properties on the items in the `IEnumerable` for those two values.  What are you trying to do with `CoId` in the `ViewBag`?

Comment: I am trying to have the user select an option and then using the CoId call a URL.action() that takes the CoId as a parameter.

Comment: Well, provide the `CoId` to your call, but change the property being specified in your `DropDownFor` to be `Id`.

Answer (score 0):

> What is m=>m.Id actually doing here?

Is seting the value from your model into your DDL.

> Is "CoId" being set to value and "CompanyName" set to text?

Yes and no, "CoId" is the value from your DDL, but, you don't have any propertie "CoId", so, you need to change to "Id".